# How to display a HTML file and text with flask python

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to make a website that displays text I can change (preferably instantly).
I was able to do this with:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    global val
    return str(val)
```

along with a function running at the same time allowing me to change the variable "val"

However, now I would like to be able to display data and receive data from the user. To do this I used an HTML template, however I am not able to instantly change the data in the HTML file, so I can not change the data easily.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('form.html')
```

I would like to be able to display this HTML template, and the variable "val" at the same time.
I have tried:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    global val
    return str(val), render_template('form.html')
```

But this also does not work and it gives an error.

Comment: templates are designed to display variables (such as your var `val`). Read up on flask's templating docs and add your `val` variable to your template. Each time it's displayed, it will update with the current value of `val`.

Comment: @DanielleM. My template is an HTML file, I have no experience with HTML, and do not understand how I can add `val` to the template as it is a variable in the python code.

Comment: That's why I suggested reading the docs :) Add this to yourform.html somewhere: `<h3>{{ my_val }}</h3>`, then `return` your template with `render_template('form.html', my_val=val)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `render_template("form.html" , str=str)`

And in `form.html`

```html
<body>
   <p>{{str}}</p>
</body>
```

This way using  `jinja` syntax you can display the variable

thank you